# Print corresponding words to word-counts (Bag-of-Words)

Tags: python, numpy

my code creates for every document I am processing a vector based Bag-of-words.

It works and prints the frequency of every single word in the document. Additionally I would like to print every word just right in front of the number, just like this:

```py
['word', 15]
```

I tried it on my own. What I get right now looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
for doc in docsClean:

    bag_vector = np.zeros(len(doc))

    for w in doc:
        for i,word in enumerate(doc):
            if word == w:
                bag_vector[i] += 1

    print(bag_vector)
    print("{0},{1}\n".format(w,bag_vector[i]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `dict` to store the frequency of each word.

There is already an inbuilt python feature to do this - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
from collections import Counter

# Random words
words = ['lacteal', 'brominating', 'postmycotic', 'legazpi', 'enclosing', 'arytaenoid', 'brominating', 'postmycotic', 'legazpi', 'enclosing']
frequency = Counter(words)

print(frequency)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'brominating': 2, 'postmycotic': 2, 'legazpi': 2, 'enclosing': 2, 'lacteal': 1, 'arytaenoid': 1})
```

If, for any reason, you don't want to use collections.Counter, here is a simple code to do the same task.

```py
words = ['lacteal', 'brominating', 'postmycotic', 'legazpi', 'enclosing', 'arytaenoid', 'brominating', 'postmycotic', 'legazpi', 'enclosing']

freq = {}  # Empty dict

for word in words:
    freq[word] = freq.get(word, 0) + 1

print(freq)
```

This code works by adding 1 to the frequency of `word`, if it is already present in `freq`, otherwise `freq.get(word, 0)` returns `0`, so the frequency of a new word gets stored as `1`.

Output:

```
{'lacteal': 1, 'brominating': 2, 'postmycotic': 2, 'legazpi': 2, 'enclosing': 2, 'arytaenoid': 1}
```